# How to jump to a slide in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

I have to prepare a beamer presentation, but depending on the audience, during the presentation I might decide to skip some material.  Is there a way to do this without having to skip quickly through the slides?  I seem to remember that there was a command, but I forgot what it was and anyway I never succeeded in having it work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Never worked with beamer presentation, but have you tried the hyperref package and `\label` and `\ref`?

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It was not what I was looking for but perhaps it works.  Thank you to you and to Patrick.

Comment: if you give us an MWE, we can have a more sorrow look into it. With the question you've asked, hyperref is a completely satisfying solution.

Answer (score 11):

Beamer offers a variety of navigation buttons for such purposes. Together with the `\hyperlink` command they can be used to conveniently jump to other slides or frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
1

\hyperlink{foo}{\beamerskipbutton{skip slide}}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=foo]
3
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For more examples, please see section `11.1 Adding Hyperlinks and Buttons` from the beamer user guide.

Comment: `[label=foo]` doesn't work for me. I need to use `\label{foo}` instead for this to work.

Answer (score 11):

0. Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the preamble. (Or, immediately above `\begin{document}`)
1. Label the frame you want to go to. For this, add `\label{SOME_NAME}` after `\begin{frame}`.
2. Where needed, place the icon that links to that slide:

   ```
    \hyperlink{SOME_NAME}{\beamerbutton{link}}
   ```

which produces this:

[image]

You can change the icon style and text accordingly.

3. If you want to go back to the slide you were before, you can add another link button as above. For neatness, (e.g. if going back to a slide shown before), this button can be **invisible**. For instance, add this:

   ```
    \hyperlink{back}{\hspace{3cm}}
   ```

where `back` is the label of the original slide.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's a way to have buttons in the footline. A "go back" button takes you to the table of contents from any slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber%
  \hspace*{2em}%
  \parbox[c]{2pt}{\makebox[0pt][c]{% doesn't use any horizontal space
    \hyperlink{frameTOC}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}%
  }}%
  \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=frameTOC]\thispagestyle{empty}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\hyperlink{labelOne}{\beamergotobutton{}}] Go to first target slide
\begin{itemize}
\item[] There is a filler side in between to check that navigation works
\end{itemize}
\item[\hyperlink{labelTwo}{\beamergotobutton{}}] Go to second target slide (third slide in the deck)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=labelOne]
\frametitle{Some More Content}
This slide is labeled and used as first target. The button in the bottom right corner takes you back to the table of content.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some Content}
This slide is not labeled and not used as target.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=labelTwo]
\frametitle{Some Extra Content}
This slide is labeled and used as second target.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** I noticed problems with `\hyperlink` when compiling with `XeLaTeX`. Inserting the following right at the top seemed to fix it. It also increases the size of the white arrows inside the buttons, which I happen to like. To use the other beamer buttons with empty text and xelatex, one would have to redefine their symbol in the same manner.

```
\def\insertgotosymbol{$\blacktriangleright$}% fix hyperlink with empty text when compiling with XeLaTeX
\def\insertreturnsymbol{$\blacktriangleleft$}% fix hyperlink with empty text when compiling with XeLaTeX
```

Comment: xelatex does not deal well with non-text content in hyperlinks.It also causes some other problems with beamer. I would suggest to use lualatex instead if that's compatible with your document.

Comment: thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I'll give lualatex a try!

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `hyperref` package and create references to the slides you want to view.